# Read from basic stream (httpRequestStream)

Tags: c#, .net, http, stream

I have a basic stream which is the stream of HTTP request 
and

```
var s=new HttpListener().GetContext().Request.InputStream;
```

I want to read the stream (which contain non-Character content, because i've sent the packet)

When we wrap this stream by StreamReader then we use the ReadToEnd() function of StreamReader it can read the whole stream and return a string...

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1/");
listener.Start();
var context = listener.GetContext();
var sr = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream);
string x=sr.ReadToEnd(); //This Workds
```

but since it has nonCharacter content we cant use StremReader (i tried all encoding mechanisms..using string is just wrong).And i Cant use the function

```
context.Request.InputStream.Read(buffer,position,Len)
```

because I cant get the length of the stream, InputStream.Length always throws an exception and cant be used..and i dont want to create a small protocol like [size][file] and read first size then the file ...somehow the StreamReader can get the length ..and i just want to know how .
I also tried this and it didn't work

```
List<byte> bb = new List<byte>();
var ss = context.Request.InputStream;
byte b = (byte)ss.ReadByte();
while (b >= 0)
{
    bb.Add(b);
    b = (byte)ss.ReadByte();
}
```

I've solved it by the following

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\cygwin\\home\\Dff.rar", FileMode.Create);
byte[] file = new byte[1024 * 1024];
int finishedBytes = ss.Read(file, 0, file.Length);
while (finishedBytes > 0)
{
    fs.Write(file, 0, finishedBytes);
    finishedBytes = ss.Read(file, 0, file.Length);
}
fs.Close();
```

thanks Jon , Douglas

Comment: I assume your last version should work. Two hints:
(1) Learn to use the 'using' statement for automatically closing the FileStream.
(2) You probably don't need such a massive byte[] buffer, since you're unlikely to read that much data in any single Read call. A size of around 8192 would probably be enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your bug lies in the following line:

```
byte b = (byte)ss.ReadByte();
```

The `byte` type is unsigned; when [`Stream.ReadByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readbyte.aspx) returns -1 at the end of the stream, you’re indiscriminately casting it to `byte`, which converts it to 255 and, therefore, satisfies the `b >= 0` condition. It is helpful to note that the return type is `int`, not `byte`, for this very reason.

A quick-and-dirty fix for your code:

```
List<byte> bb = new List<byte>();
var ss = context.Request.InputStream;
int next = ss.ReadByte();
while (next != -1)
{
    bb.Add((byte)next);
    next = ss.ReadByte();
}
```

The following solution is more efficient, since it avoids the byte-by-byte reads incurred by the `ReadByte` calls, and uses a dynamically-expanding byte array for `Read` calls instead (similar to the way that `List<T>` is internally implemented):

```
var ss = context.Request.InputStream;

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int totalCount = 0;

while (true)
{
    int currentCount = ss.Read(buffer, totalCount, buffer.Length - totalCount);
    if (currentCount == 0)
        break;

    totalCount += currentCount;
    if (totalCount == buffer.Length)
        Array.Resize(ref buffer, buffer.Length * 2);
}

Array.Resize(ref buffer, totalCount);
```

Comment: Lol, i just saw your comment..thanks for the info ...but I will use the file as the second array ..so I wont need resizing the array

Answer (score 5):

`StreamReader` cannot get the length either -- it seems there's some confusion regarding the third parameter of [`Stream.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx). That parameter specifies the *maximum* number of bytes that will be read, which does not need (and really cannot) be equal to the number of bytes actually available in the stream. You just call `Read` in a loop until it returns `0`, in which case you know you have reached the end of the stream. This is all documented on MSDN, and it's also exactly how `StreamReader` does it.

There's also no problem in reading the request with `StreamReader` and getting it into `string`; strings are binary safe in .NET, so you 're covered. The problem will be making sense of the contents of the string, but we can't really talk about that since you don't provide any relevant information.

Comment: True ..I didnt explain that much ..What I ment by the len is an already created byte[] b=new byte[len] but this len i cant get it ..and my problem with strings is that we must use encoding in both ways from bytes to string and vise versa..but in the encoding step always messes my bytes ..

Comment: And i triend var sr = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream, Encoding.ASCII); and unicode and UTF8 then used "New AsciiEncoding().GetBytes(str)" and i got scrumbled bytes ..

Comment: and the ReadByte function returns -1 at end of stream ..still got infinite loop..

Comment: @CnativeFreak: You *can not* and you also **need not** get the length. Pick your own buffer size and read repeatedly. Also, *you cannot use any encoding other than ASCII because that will mess up your input data.* But you still have not provided any info on what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpRequestStream` won't give you the length, but you can get it from the `HttpListenerRequest.ContentLength64` property. Like Jon said, make sure you observe the return value from the `Read` method. In my case, we get buffered reads and cannot read our entire 226KB payload in one go.

Try

```
    byte[] getPayload(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        int length = (int)context.Request.ContentLength64;
        byte[] payload = new byte[length];
        int numRead = 0;
        while (numRead < length)
            numRead += context.Request.InputStream.Read(payload, numRead, length - numRead);

        return payload;
    }
```